# clases css incluidas en los navegadores

Tags: css, navegador-web

Los navegadores poseen hojas de estilos por defecto que yo como programador pueda utilizar ?

Algo como por ejemplo

```
<span class="chrome_header_default"></span>
```

He indagado en la red y solo he logrado encontrar los estilos por defecto que los navegadores le aplican a los elementos `html` como por ejemplo el margen a los `h1` o el tamaño de las fuentes de estos.

Comment: Algunos navegadores añaden algunos atributos por defecto como el margin. Puedes desactivarlos con *{ margin: 0; }. Si lo que quieres es una plantilla por defecto, usa bootstrap por ejemplo

Comment: @Tefef pudiera usar una hoja de estilos creada incluso por mi pero este no es el caso.

Comment: Cuál sería el propósito?

Comment: @JheymanMejia Estoy culminando de reinventar la rueda, un Framework de PHP y no quiero cargarlo de dependencias que no serán utilizadas con frecuencias.

Comment: Voy a proceder a crear una hoja de estilo personalizada ya que lo que pretendía me parece que no existe.

Answer (score 2):

Cada navegador aplica unos estilos predeterminados, en este repositorio de [GitHub](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css) puedes encontrar los valores por defecto para:

- [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css)
- [IE](http://web.archive.org/web/20170122223926/http://www.iecss.com/)
- [Chrome / Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)
- [Opera](http://web.archive.org/web/20161031005401/http://www.iecss.com/opera-10.51.css)
- [HTML4 (W3C)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)
- [HTML5 (W3C)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html)

---

Fuente y créditos: [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements/22510220#22510220)

Comment: Esta no es la respuesta que busco, ya había leído esto como comentaba en mi pregunta.